# SSH connection always asking for password

Tags: ssh

I’m working on Hadoop multi node cluster, so nodes communicate using SSH
here is my problem:

- I have 3 computers connected to the same router
- This router sometimes gets restarted so the IP adress for the machines might change
- Every time this happens I edit `/etc/hosts` file updating IP address of machines named (`master`, `slave1`, `slave2`) and it tells that this machine will be added.

At first when I configured SSH generating the key and copying it to other machines it worked perfectly, I could use `ssh slave1` from master and logging in with no password prompt:

- I have edited `sshd_config` file and changed `PubkeyAuthentication` to `no`
- Tried regenerating ssh key and used `ssh-copy-id` to copy it again to other computers (something like `ssh-copy-id ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@host`in all computers)

It's ok for me to change the IP adress manually because I had big trouble trying to make IP address static, but I need to use `ssh host` with no password prompt.

Comment: This sounds a lot more complex than it needs to be. First, you should not be editing `/etc/hosts` for something like this; your machines should all have their proper hostnames used for SSH. Next, IP address changes have nothing to do with SSH. Also, why would you disable `PubkeyAuthentication` with `no`? That is the exact opposite of what to describe you want to do? That should be set to `yes`.

Comment: yeah i was confused, I should have set PasswordAuthentication to not and not PubkeyAuthentication

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `PubkeyAuthentication` to `yes` in the `sshd_config` (on the server) to use the keys you've copied over.

(Once that is working you should also disable passwords with `PasswordAuthentication no` to prevent brute force guessing).

Instead of editing `/etc/hosts` (which requires root privileges) you can edit or create a user config `~/.ssh/config`. (This only applies to ssh though). It would look something like:

```
Host slave1
  Hostname 192.168.1.101
  User bob
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  PubkeyAuthentication yes`

Host slave2
  Hostname 192.168.1.102
  User bobby`

Host master
  Hostname 192.168.1.100
  User admin`
```

Replace `192.x.x.x` with your addresses and change it to your needs (`man ssh_config` is a great help here).

With this you will be able to type `ssh slave1` and have all kinds of settings applied.

`sshd_config` configures the SSH *server* and `ssh_config` configures the SSH *client* (for all users) and per user in `~/.ssh/config`.

The issue of changing IP addresses is best discussed in a separate question but I'd look into locking the DHCP leases (if you have access to the router), looking into putting `inform 192.168.1.101` in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` (if you use dhcpcd) or giving static IP addresses another go.